# Why selenium does not provide any info with NoSuchElementException

Tags: selenium, selenium-chromedriver

I'm using webdriver with firefox in Java.
I'm searching for elements by using annotations, eg.:

```
@FindBy(id = "terminal")
private WebElement selectTerminal;
```

lets say that page fails to render, and for some reason this element does not get rendered. The error message is very obscure and if i'm running tests remotely on Jenkins, its very hard to debug and see what exactly happend, eg.:

```
The element could not be found (WARNING: The server did not provide any stacktrace information)
Command duration or timeout: 72 milliseconds
For documentation on this error, please visit: http://seleniumhq.org/exceptions/no_such_element.html
Build info: version: '2.20.0', revision: '16008', time: '2012-02-28 15:00:40'
System info: os.name: 'Linux', os.arch: 'i386', os.version: '2.6.32-312-ec2', java.version: '1.6.0_20'
Driver info: driver.version: RemoteWebDriver
```

How could i get more detailed info that would contain the selector? Of course i could wrap it up in some kind of helper method, with try/catch, etc. But what i want to know is why it is not displaying the selector, and how can i get rid of that WARNING ?

Thanks!

Comment: Also, the webpage isn't really helpful. This really is a pain and I am looking forward for a solution. In my case, it was the custom catch, log the selector and take of a screenshot.

Comment: Looking at the source of org.openqa.selenium.remote.ErrorHandler class i see comment like this, so guess this is expected behavior:   //If serverError is null, then the server did not provide a className (only expected if
    // the server is a Java process) or a stack trace. The lack of a className is OK, but
    // not having a stacktrace really hurts our ability to debug problems.

Comment: I had similar issues in PHP and also ended up wrapping things in a try/catch block. Seems to be the only thing for it...

Answer (score 0):

While this is not an ideal solution, it's what helped me with the same issue.

Enable logging to a file by setting webdriver system property E.g.

```
-Dwebdriver.firefox.logfile=/tmp/ff.log
```

or in your test code:

```
System.setProperty("webdriver.firefox.logfile", "/tmp/ff.log")
```

Then in ff.log you should see output where the error occurred e.g.

```
[6.389][FINE]:      Command received (/session/5a4c8a0a7ef5453467687267348e8cb3/element)    with params {
"using": "xpath",
"value": "//input[@class='login-submit']
}

[6.389][FINER]:     Waiting for all views to stop loading...
[6.390][FINER]:     Done waiting for all views to stop loading
[6.505][FINER]:     Waiting for all views to stop loading...
[6.506][FINER]:     Done waiting for all views to stop loading
[6.506][WARNING]:   Command finished (/session/5a4c8a0a7ef5453467687267348e8cb3/element)   with response {
   "sessionId": "5a4c8a0a7ef5453467687267348e8cb3",
    "status": 7,
    "value": {
    "message": "The element could not be found"
 }
}
```

At least now I can see which element it was based on the **xpath**. This works with ChromeDriver as well